# Summary of people posting a hashtag on Google+?

Tags: google-plus

How can I get a summary of who is posting the most entries with a given hashtag on Google+?
For example, how can I know who has posted the most in Google+ with the hashtag `#AngryBirds`?

Comment: I suppose not much more happened recently here that I still don't get a positive result from this answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is very unlikely you will find that out.

- It would require monitoring all G+ user posts from 3rd party site, which would be very inaccurate due to permissions (circles), not to mention disliked by Google.
- If someone got the permission from `#angry birds` to track notifications and made the 3rd party server/site, mostly no one would bother to do this.
- Downloading scripts could work (if those existed) but it would only make a list from people you circled (and other way around).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, but I don't think that's possible as of now.

But do have a look at this blog post which talks about measuring the audience size for a particular hashtag (not who uses it particularly).

http://blog.ouseful.info/2012/02/09/what-is-the-potential-audience-size-for-a-hashtag-community/

It's written keeping in mind twitter hashtags, but the scripts given there might be useful if you want to build your own for Google+.

Hope that helps!